# how to update dns after a changing resolvconf

Tags: 16.04, dns, resolvconf

I need to edit my system's dns nameservers, without rebooting, on a system i believe uses `resolveconf`.  The changes i make to `/etc/resolvconf/resolve.conf.d/base` ARE reflected on full reboot, but I need to update the local dns nameservers without rebooting.  On ubuntu16.04

As I've understood the docs, my system uses resolvconf, and my `/etc/resolv.conf` file is autogenerated from `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` (as well as `head` and `tail`).  I edited `base` and need to get my system to use the new nameservers.

All the answers I've found seem to direct me to `sudo resolvconf -u` and (possibly) restart the `network-manager` service.  From the `man` page i also tried `--enable-udpates` and re-running the `-u`.

None of my changes in `base` seem to be reflected in `resolve.conf` after these steps, and `nslookup` is using the former contents.

How do i update my system to use the new dns servers I'm trying to set (and, if my statements above about what ubuntu uses are wrong or incomplete, please correct me!)

Thank you!

Comment: If you're using the network-manager, have you tried to set up the DNS server in the network manager config ? Under Ubuntu when editing a connection in the IPv4/6 tab: "Additional DNS Server". Just reconnect after saving.

Comment: @JonnyTischbein - when i open 'network connections' it appears to reflect resolve.conf.  since ubuntu uses resolveconf, this will be overwritten.  As mentioned, this only seems to be happening on reboot, so I can manually edit resolve.conf with the needed changes (which then take effect immediately).  It does not, obvously, persist though which is the problem